# Calling Function not Displaying Results

Tags: c++, function, loops, functional-programming

I Create an `array` of `5 x 5` with random numbers in the following way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int a[5][5];
    int randomNumber;
    srand (time(NULL));
    // output each array element's value                      
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
          cout << endl;
        for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) {
             a[i][j] = randomNumber;
             randomNumber = rand() %100 + 1;
             cout << a[i][j] << "  ";
        }
       cout << endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

And the output of this is given below 5 x 5 Array.[image]

But when i wrap my loop into a function and then calling it. Then its not showing any results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {

   // output each array element's value   
   cout <<"Array Results are.....";
   int PopulateArray();                   

  return 0;
}

int PopulateArray(){
int a[5][5];
int randomNumber;
srand (time(NULL));

for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {

       cout << endl;

    for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) {
        a[i][j] = randomNumber;
        randomNumber = rand() %100 + 1;
        cout << a[i][j] << "  ";
      }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

And now the results are like this

[image]

**Problem**

Why results are not showing when i wrap my `loop` in `function`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` function never call `PopulateArray`. The line `int PopulateArray();` declares the function it does not call it.

Answer (score 0):

You call the function incorrectly. This line in your code:

```
int PopulateArray();
```

does not really call the function, it just **declares** it. So all the program does is printing text to cout, then it declares a function without executing it, and then exits. The correct way to call is just:

```
PopulateArray();
```

BTW there is no reason for this function to return an int as no integer is returned from it.